# Dynamic Memory Allocation Using Temporary Array

Tags: c, arrays, memory, dynamic, allocation

I'm having trouble dynamically allocating memory for an array. 
The program is simply supposed to exchange the swap the first row with the second, and the third with the forth. I am getting strange results like:

Enter string: hello

Enter string: how are you

Enter string: i'm good thanks

Enter string: bye

Enter string: bai

Enter string: xx

=========================

how are you

!i'm good thanks

hello

!how are you

bye

!bai

i'm good thanks

!bye

bai

!xx

```
    int count = 0;
    char *lines[MAX_LINES];
    char *tmp[50]; 


    printf("Enter string: ");
    fgets(tmp, 50, stdin);
    lines[count] = (char *) malloc((strlen(tmp)+1) * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(lines[count], tmp); 

    while(strcmp("xx\n", lines[count])){
            count++;
            printf("Enter string: ");
            fgets(tmp, 50, stdin); 
            lines[count] = (char *) malloc((strlen(tmp)+1)* sizeof(char));

            strcpy(lines[count], tmp); 
    }

void exchange(char * records[])
{
    char * temp;
    temp = records[0];
    records[0] = records[1];
    records[1] = temp;

    temp = records[2];
    records[2] = records[3];
    records[3] = temp; 

}

void printArray(char * inputs[], int row, int col)
{
    int i, j;

    for(i = 0; i < row; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < col; j++){
            printf("%c", inputs[i][j]);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: you can edit your first question instead of posting a new one.

Answer (score 0):

This is not good:

```
char *tmp[50];
```

You intended to do this:

```
char tmp[50];
```

Strangely enough, it'll kinda work, but your compiler should have been throwing up warnings everywhere.

I think your main problem is your `printArray` function, which doesn't check for the NULL terminator in a string.  So it's gonna run right off the end of most of them.

Instead of printing character-by-character, do this:

```
void printArray(char * inputs[], int length)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < length; i++){
        printf("%s", inputs[i]);
    }
}
```

Here's a tip on using `malloc`.  Don't cast the result, and if you're reserving space for `char` values, don't use `sizeof(char)` -- it's always 1.

```
lines[count] = malloc( strlen(tmp) + 1 );
```